# Javascript validation:

Tags: javascript, validation, client-side

i am having this problem where those validation stopped working starting from the email validation part onwards.

i just couldn't figure out why even after days looking at it and just wondering if someone can point out my mistake here?

Javascript part:

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["firstname"].value;

if (x==null || x=="")
    {
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    return false;
    }

var x=document.forms["myForm"]["lastname"].value;

if (x==null || x=="")
    {
    alert("Last name must be filled out");
    return false;
    }

var x=document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;

if (x==null || x=="" || x < 18 || x > 110 || isNaN(x))
    {
    alert("Age must be 18-110");
    return false;
    }

var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");

if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length)
    {
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
    }

var x=document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
var pattern = /^\(?([0-9]{2})\)?[ ]+([0-9]{4})[ ]+([0-9]{4})$/;

if (x==null || x=="")
    {
    alert("Not a valid phone number");
    return false;
    } else if (x.match(pattern)) {
    return true;
    } else {
    alert ("Phone number must be in the following format: xx xxxx xxxx");
    return false;
    }
}
```

and this is the form part:

```
<form id="myForm" action="../includes/create-user.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
    <div id = "table">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Age: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="age" id="age"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>E-mail (username): </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="user" id="user1"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password: </td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass1"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Register"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Just to make sure you understand, Client Side validation means that the client will be able to disable your validation scripts and submit un-validated content to your website anyway. The Browser is always in the Hands of the Enemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that stands out is that you specify your field:

```
<td><input type="text" name="user" id="user1"/></td>
```

with id = 'user1'
and you look in your script for email

```
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up! i've changed it to 'user1' in the script part and it worked. sorry i shouldn't have missed that.